# Splunk search Regex: to filter timestamp and userId

Tags: regex, splunk

Below the text want to extract timestamp align with UserId from the below line and group it

```
    2020-10-12 12:30:22.540  INFO 1 --- [enerContainer-4] c.t.t.o.s.s.UserPrepaidService       : Validating the user with UserID:1111 systemID:sys111
```

From below whole logs

```
2020-10-12 12:30:22.538  INFO 1 --- [ener-4] c.t.t.o.s.service.UserService        :    AccountDetails":[{"snumber":"2222","sdetails":[{"sId":"0474889018","sType":"Java","plan":[{"snumber":"sdds22"}]}]}]}
    2020-10-12 12:30:22.538  INFO 1 --- [ener-4] c.t.t.o.s.service.ReceiverService        : Received userType is:Normal
    2020-10-12 12:30:22.540  INFO 1 --- [enerContainer-4] c.t.t.o.s.s.UserPrepaidService       : Validating the user with UserID:1111 systemID:sys111 
    2020-10-12 12:30:22.540  INFO 1 --- [enerContainer-4] c.t.t.o.s.util.CommonUtil                : The  Code is valid for userId: 1111 systemId: sys111
    2020-10-12 12:30:22.577  INFO 1 --- [enerContainer-4] c.t.t.o.s.r.Dao        : Saving user into dB ..... with User-ID:1111
```

....

same repetitive line

Below is my SPL search commands it returns only userid group by from that specific line.

But I want the time stamp as well from that line and group by it with time chart

```
index="tis" logGroup="/ecs/logsmy" "logEvents{}.message"="*Validating the user with UserID*" | spath output=myfield path=logEvents{}.message | rex field=myfield "(?<=Validating the user with UserID:)(?<userId>[0-9]+)(?= systemID:)" |  table userId | dedup userId | stats count values(userId) by userId
```

Basically I tired the below

```
(^(?<dtime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d+) )(?<=Validating the user with UserID:)(?<userId>[0-9]+)(?= systemID:)
```

but it gave all the time stamp not specifically the line I mentioned above

Comment: I have seen this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333471/regex-splunk-extract-timestamp-from-the-below-text) today, did the suggestion in the comments from Wiktor not work?

Comment: yes its not work gave all the time stamp of the logs....I am removing that question

Comment: Can you update the question with the pattern that you did try?

Comment: (^(?<dtime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d+) )(?<=Validating the user with UserID:)(?<userId>[0-9]+)(?= systemID:)

Comment: So you want to match both parts, not only the timestamp?

Comment: Then you could use 2 capturing groups `^\s*(?<dtime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d+).*\bValidating the user with UserID:(?<userId>[0-9]+)(?= systemID:)` https://regex101.com/r/BM7rFv/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the lookaround right after matching the timestamp pattern, but you have to first move to the postition where the lookbehind is true.

If you want both values, you can match `Validating the user with UserID:` and  `systemID:` instead of using a lookaround.

If there are leading whitspace chars, you could match them with `\s` or `[^\S\r\n]*`

```
^\s*(?<dtime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d+).*\bValidating the user with UserID:(?<userId>[0-9]+) systemID:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GuWUBh/1)